# Find the sum of all subsets of a given array with max size of the subset at most k

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given and array **A** = [1, 2, 3] and **k** = 2, the subsets will be: [1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3] and their sum will be 18.

constraints: |A| = 1000000, A[i] < 1000000

note: ans has to be returned in modulo 10^9+7

I have solved it using the last row of pascals triangle of size n(size of array). For the above eg. it is 121. As **k**=2, I sum the first 2 terms of **1 2 1** which is 1+2=3. I multiply each term of the array by this factor which gives me 3*1 + 3*2 + 3*3 = 18. This works because each number occurs that many number of times in all subsets.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that the sum of first binomial coefficients is a binomial coefficients, here c(3,2) = c(3, 1). There have been several posts already here on SO on how to calculate efficiently a binomial coefficient mod P. Besides, except this detail, it seems to me that your approach is the good one

Comment: Yes, each term appears `(0, n - 1) + (1, n - 1) + (2, n - 1) + ... + (k - 1, n - 1)` times; so you have to effiently find the sum of the binomial coefficients